# Linux Azure Function - how to change the port used by underlying container?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-linux

I am trying to deploy Azure function to Linux environment. Function needs to use hybrid connection to connect to on-prem API on port 80.

After deploy I receive the following error "Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable".
Here is the output from docker logs:

```
2023-03-22T11:44:50.580612973Z Unhandled exception on 03/22/2023 11:44:50: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to bind to address http://[::]:80: address already in use.)
2023-03-22T11:44:50.580768273Z  ---> System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:80: address already in use.
2023-03-22T11:44:50.580781573Z  ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use
2023-03-22T11:44:50.580785873Z  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (98): Address already in use
2023-03-22T11:44:50.580883973Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
2023-03-22T11:44:50.580895373Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
2023-03-22T11:44:50.580899573Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
```

Setting `WEBSITES_PORT` to another port doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stumbled upon [this](https://azureossd.github.io/2023/02/15/Whats-the-difference-between-PORT-and-WEBSITES_PORT/index.html) article which helped me resolve the issue.
After setting the `PORT` to value `8080`, container boots normally.

> **PORT is for App Service on Linux “Blessed” Images.**
>
> tldr: On App Service Linux, using Blessed Images - PORT directly
> influences the container port of the docker run command. Just like
> what is explained in the WEBSITES_PORT section. However, most times,
> you most likely don’t need to alter it.
>
> If for some reason you need to change the default container port (that
> your application would be listening on), you can use the PORT
> variable.
>
> WEBSITES_PORT has no effect here. Adding this as an App Setting will
> not change the port - if you need to change the port from the default
> port being ran, then you must use the PORT App Setting.
>
> The following are the default ports for Blessed Image stacks (possibly
> subject to change):
>
> ```
> Node: 8080
> Python: 8000
> Java SE / Tomcat: 80
> Go (experimental): 8080
> .NET: 8080
> Ruby: 8080
> PHP: 8080
> ```